# Onchange event not working in background page when Modal window pops up in IE

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, bootstrap-modal

I had a ColdFusion page and a Bootstrap page. In jQuery on ready function I was trying to get the Bootstrap modal window with active background, so that the user can work on Background as well as Modal window page. I have few fields on the Background page, as soon as user tabs out of the field in Background page an onChange event is should fire. But in My scenario this event is not firing in IE, It works fine in Firefox and Chrome. Here is the code below. 
Modal Window Page:

```
<div id="getCashFlowModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" style="height:50%;width:39%">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm"  style="width:auto">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h5 class="modal-title">Project Cost Summary</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery OnReady:

```
$("#CommonCashFlow").load('CashFlowModalWindow.cfm', function() {
    $("#getCashFlowModal").modal('show');});
    $('.modal-backdrop').removeClass("modal-backdrop");   
    $("#getCashFlowModal").draggable({
       handle: ".modal-header"
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `onchange` here? This sounds more like `onblur` to me. `onchange` is fired if the value changed, `onblur` is fired if the focus is lost.

Comment: tried with Onblur and the event is not firing up

Comment: Can you provide a full example? The code you posted doesn't contain any event binding for `onchange`.